# Tensorflow sequence to sequence with LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am new to python. When I try to run the below program I get the following error.

> ValueError: Variable model/embedding/seq2seq/seq2seq_encode/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?

How do I solve the error?
Below is the code which creates the lstm model:

```
def create_model(encode_seqs, decode_seqs, src_vocab_size,emb_dim,is_train=True, reuse=False):

    with tf.variable_scope("model", reuse=reuse):
        with tf.variable_scope("embedding") as vs:

              tl.layers.set_name_reuse(True)
              net_encode = EmbeddingInputlayer(
                inputs = encode_seqs,
                vocabulary_size = src_vocab_size,
                embedding_size = emb_dim,
                name = 'seq_embedding')

              vs.reuse_variables()


              net_decode = EmbeddingInputlayer(
                inputs = decode_seqs,
                vocabulary_size = src_vocab_size,
                embedding_size = emb_dim,
                name = 'seq_embedding')

              net_rnn = Seq2Seq(net_encode, net_decode,
                cell_fn = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell,
                n_hidden = emb_dim,
                initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1),
                encode_sequence_length = retrieve_seq_length_op2(encode_seqs),
                decode_sequence_length = retrieve_seq_length_op2(decode_seqs),
                initial_state_encode = None,
                dropout = (0.5 if is_train else None),
                n_layer = 3,
                return_seq_2d = True,
                name = 'seq2seq')

         net_out = DenseLayer(net_rnn, n_units=src_vocab_size, act=tf.identity, name='output')

    return net_out, net_rnn
```

I have looked at simliar questions but none of the solutions seem to solve my problem.